# How to use reCAPTCHA?

Tags: javascript, forms, response, recaptcha, verification

I have read all the documentation for reCAPTCHA by Google, but it doesn't show any example code.

Could anyone help me with the verification code so a form submits only when the `get_response()` function is returned or something.

I notice that I don't have to implement it within an ASP.NET module, but instead can use just JavaScript.

Here is the page I'm talking about: http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/recaptcha/docs/display.html

Answer (score 4):

The page you mentioned only shows how to **display** the reCAPTCHA using only JavaScript.

There is **no** method to verify the reCAPTCHA using only JavaScript because of two reasons:

1. To verify the reCAPTCHA, you have to use your private key, as explained in [Verifying the User's Answer Without Plugins](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/recaptcha/docs/verify.html). Doing so with client-side scripting ultimately exposes the private key. reCAPCTHA relies on its secrecy.
2. Even if there was a way, it would be useless. Any method of preventing the form's submission using JavaScript can be easily undone (using a [User Script](http://greasemonkey.mozdev.org/authoring.html), for example) and, therefore, offers no protection at all.

To verify the reCPATCHA, you can use either the method described in the link in 1. or [one of their plugins](http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/intro.html#Plugins). Either way, you need some kind of server-side scripting (PHP, ASP, Perl, etc.).

Comment: That cant be all true. There would be no need for javascript if I were to use this within a plugin (asp.net would be my choice) apart from perhaps a verification script however as you rightly said, that could jeopardize the security of reCAPTCHA, perhaps there is a solution that we have missed? Thanks though man.

Comment: reCAPCTHA requires two steps: displaying the challenge and verifying the response. Both can be achieved with or without a plugin. *There would be no need for javascript if I were to use this within a plugin.* Well, it is slightly either to deal with one plugin and two. Also, there are scenarios where the form and its destination are on two different locations. The form page might not have server-side scripting available. *Perhaps there is a solution that we have missed?* There isn't. I've expanded my answer. If you don't know about it already, I suggest you follow the link about User Scripts.